# How to reset Firefox console without refreshing the page?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

How can I reset a Firefox [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) in order to be able to use variables already declared?

`console.clear()` will only clear the output. All variables already declared are sticking in memory. I'm trying to get rid of:

```
Error: "SyntaxError: redeclaration of..."
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When testing something, use the same construction you would (well, should) use to prevent code and variables being dropped in the global scope. Use Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) and place your code in it. Each IIFE is it's own context, so re-declaring is not a problem.

```
(function () {
  const myConstant = 1;

  console.log(myConstant);
}());
```

Note that [Chrome 80](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/devtools#redeclarations) allows redeclaration of const and let. There exists [a relevant bug in bugzilla for Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1580891).

Comment: I'm fully aware that IIFE prevent polluting the global scope. However using this technique each time I want to reuse the same variable's name is quite disturbing. what I'm looking for is some sort of a reset button that clears the global scope or maybe there is a way to confugure the console to do so whenever I hit Enter to write a new line of code. Anyway, thanks for your smart answer. I'll try to be less lazy when experimenting with code.

Comment: Remember that you can use the up-arrow to retrieve the last written lines. The console is nothing than a fancy interface for the javascript on the current page. I don't think there is an easy way to "clear" it. The only way you can reuse a constant is if that constant goes out of scope, such as above.

Comment: More simply, you can wrap the code inside braces: `{ // lots of code }`.

Comment: This solution is more convenient than it may seem at first; I assumed I would have to plan ahead for this situation. But you can wrap your code in a `{ ... }` *when/if* you get the redeclaration error, even if you already have a `let`/`const` with the same name defined in the outer-most console scope. (I know these are basic JavaScript scoping rules, but it didn't occur to me until I tried.)

Answer (score 5):

if refreshing the page will reset the console, then you can use `location.reload()` to refresh the page via console.

Answer (score -1):

clearHistory() should do it !!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't do it. Did you check it yourself?